# After URL rewriting Style sheet not working

Tags: php, css, .htaccess

Here is my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Blog?$ blog.php
RewriteRule ^Details/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) blog-single.php?id=$1

<a href="Details/<?php echo $row['id'];?>/<?php echo $row['heading'];?>" class="view"><?php echo $row['heading'];?></a>
```

After URL rewritting

http://example.com/Details/15/Top-10-Tips-for-Starting-Your-Small-Business

but on blog-single.php Style sheets not working.

On my page source url is http://example.com/Details/15/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css

how to remove 15 in my rewrited URL
or how to assign path from rewrited URL

Answer (score 0):

In this cases you can address css and js files from root directory like this:

```
http://example.com/css/style.css
```

and css files load on all pages

Comment: any way to dynamically set this

Comment: you can define a variable which you set you domain in base directory and user from that variable in the locations which you want to address css files

Comment: ok its work. but i click a menu url is http://example.com/Details/15/Home OR http://example.com/Details/15/About my actual Path is http://example.com/Details/Home or http://example.com/Details/About